# Pine Editor Trading View global variables one value for every bar

Tags: tradingview-api

Is there a option to create a variable what holds the same value over all bars.
I would like to calculate a value in on a bar and use it on the next bar.

Answer (score 1):

See more about **var** modifier, it allows to create one instance of variable for script:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
var v = close
// plots close value of the first bar
plot(v)
```